# An interesting series converging to a constant

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let $K>0$ be a constant. Suppose $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a non-decreasing positive sequence. Then the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z_n}{(K+z_1)(K+z_2)\cdots(K+z_n)}K^n=K$$

This is a quite interesting result as the series is convergent and the limit doesn't depend on the choice of $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, as long as it is a non-decreasing and positive sequence.

I have run computer simulations and this result seems to hold. However, I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but it's false for the first non-negative non-decreasing sequence I tried: 0, 0, 0, 0, ...

Comment: thanks Dan Piponi, z_n should be a positive sequence. thank you for point this out. I have edited the post. Thank you very much.

Comment: Somewhat similar sum (due Apery):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z_1z_2\cdots z_{n-1}}{(K+z_1)(K+z_2)\cdots(K+z_n)}=\frac1K.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the partial sum

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{z_n}{(K+z_1)\ldots(K+z_n)} K^n = K - \frac{K^{N+1}}{(K+z_1)\ldots(K+z_N)} $$

as is easy to prove by induction.

Comment: How do you deduce the result then?

Comment: @icv Bound the second term on the right by $K (1 + z_1/K)^{-N}$.

Comment: @icv use the fact that $z_n$ is non-decreasing.